# PHP will not run in Virtual Hosts in apache

Tags: php, apache

I cannot get PHP scripts to run in my Virtual Hosts. It works fine on the default host, but will not run in any other hosts. I've tried everything I could find on the web.  Mac 10.8 Server.

```
#/private/etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
Listen 80
Listen 8080
Listen 8010
NameVirtualHost *:80
NameVirtualHost *:8080
NameVirtualHost *:8010

#
# VirtualHost example:
# Almost any Apache directive may go into a VirtualHost container.
# The first VirtualHost section is used for all requests that do not
# match a ServerName or ServerAlias in any <VirtualHost> block.
#
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/Library/Server/Web/Data/Sites/Gradschool"
    ServerName gradschool.local
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:8080>
    DocumentRoot "/Library/Server/Web/Data/Sites/PMST"
    ServerName PMST.local
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:8010>
    DocumentRoot /library/server/web/data/sites/test
    ServerName test.local
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Does your httpd.conf include httpd-vhosts.conf?

Comment: Do static pages work for your virtual host?

Comment: Yes to both, httpd-vhosts.conf has been uncommented. Static pages work fine.

Comment: Could you find `LoadModule php5_module` line and post the context here?

Comment: In httpd.conf 
LoadModule php5_module libexec/apache2/libphp5.so

Comment: Two wild guesses. First, it looks like the Server edition stores its config file under `/Library/Server/Web/Config/apache2/httpd_server_app.conf` rather than the usual `/private/etc/apache2/httpd.conf`. Are you sure that the latter is the right config file? Second, is there a chance the php engine has been disabled for virtual hosts? It could be enabled with php_admin_flag engine on.

Comment: It's the config file that the httpd_server_app.conf points to. Where would I place the _php_admin_flag engine on_? I tried placing that between the _VirtualHost_ tags, but it didn't work.

Comment: Here is an example of VirtualHost configuration with [explicit permission for PHP](http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/SecuringPHP)

Comment: after adding _php_admin_flag engine on_ and updating PHP to a newer version, it started working. (from 5.3 to 5.4). But it seems that one website I need to manage only works with PHP 5.3. hmmmm.

Comment: @lobostome Can you put that in an answer so I can mark it answered. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

PHP could be disabled for the virtual hosts. Try enabling it with "php_admin_flag engine on":

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/Library/Server/Web/Data/Sites/Gradschool"
    ServerName gradschool.local

    <Directory /Library/Server/Web/Data/Sites/Gradschool>
            php_admin_flag engine on
            AllowOverride AuthConfig FileInfo
            Order allow,deny
            allow from all
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```